# Logging Datetime parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a datetime attribute called "published_on", and I'd like to combine form values to update my published_on value.

These are the parameters that are being passed after submitting the form:

```
"published_on"=>"05/26/2013",
 "published_on(4i)"=>"00",
 "published_on(5i)"=>"01"},
```

In my controller, I'm unable to log any of these parameters; with the following code, nothing gets printed:

```
publish_date = params[:published_on]
logger.debug "publish_date #{publish_date}"
@publish_hour = params[:"published_on"]
logger.debug "publish_hour #{@publish_hour}"
```

How do I get the published_on datetime parameters in my controller?

Comment: Are you sure those params are being pushed? What does your form look like? Edit: Nevermind, saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to include the step parameter:

publish_date = params[:step][:published_on]